# Removing R completely

Tags: r

It would be nice if someone could help.

```
(base) shazia@shazia-Lin:~$ sudo apt-get remove r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: It appears as if you haven't actually asked a question

Comment: Try `apt --fix-broken install` as suggested by apt-get and then again `sudo apt-get remove r-base`